# Retrieve zip from URL, but save with Content-Disposition filename identifier to local file

Tags: php, file, download, zip

I'm trying to download a zip from an URL, with something like this:

```
$filename = "path/to/File.zip";
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents('http://example.com/Download.zip');
```

My problem is that I want to store that file with the filename from the Content-Disposition header, not the placeholder `latest-stable`. When I predefine the path it keeps that new name.

If your try to downloading following in your browser:

http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.latest-stable.zip

The download dialog will reveal `jetpack.3.1.1.zip`, which is the filename I want, not `jetpack.latest-stable.zip`.

Comment: Use [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) and [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) / [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to get your filename.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thanks ;D Something like preg_match("/filename=(.*?.zip)/sim", $new_name, $match) and $new_name is the implode of http_response_header!

Answer (score 0):

You have the filename already (Download.zip) so you can just:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/Download.zip';
$filename = basename($url);
```

If you have more complex URLs you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the various URL components.

### Edit

From the comments you provided a URL that results in a different filename. In that case you can inspect the [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) array, which will be populated with the headers after the call to file_get_contents:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.latest-stable.zip');
print_r($http_response_header);
/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 04:11:03 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: application/zip
    [4] => Content-Length: 7303566
    [5] => Connection: close
    [6] => Cache-control: private
    [7] => Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=jetpack.3.1.1.zip
    [8] => Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 16:17:52 GMT
    [9] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    [10] => X-nc: EXPIRED lax 202
    [11] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
)
*/
```

Look for the Content-Disposition header and strip out the filename (you can use regex and/or [http_parse_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php) for this).

Comment: In this case the filename that u download in the WebView it's different from url.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.latest-stable.zip For example, webbiedave